# Combine inner regexes into one and only match if all inner regexes are satisfied regardless of multi-line or order

Tags: regex

I have a number of regexes I'm using individually to match sections of a string. I want to combine my regexes together in such a way that if ALL of the inner regexes are satisfied then it'll produce one single match. I'll redact the actual regexes because they aren't relevant and I'll use a simple example

`/(match1)|(match2)|(match3)|(match4)|(match5)/gi`

The above will match each line of the below string

```
match1
match2
match3
match4
match5
```

It will also match if they're out of order or on one line e.g.

```
match1 match4 match2 match5 match4

match1
match4
match2
match5
match4
```

However as shown by regex101.com it produces many matches (shown by the different colours). I want it so that it only produces a match if all 5 of the inner regexes (match1) through to (match5) are satisfied.

I also want it to be able to produce multiple matches for a single string that has multiple instances of the regex overall match e.g. the below should produce 3 matches

```
match1
match2
match3
match4
match5

match1
match2
match3
match4
match5

match1
match2
match3
match4
match5
```

I've tried a number of things for this including

```
Positive lookaheads
^(?=.*match1)(?=.*match2)(?=.*match3)(?=.*match4)(?=.*match5).*$
^(?=(match1)|(match2)|(match3)|(match4|(match5)))$

Non-capturing group
 ^(?:(match1)|(match2)|(match3)|(match4)|(match5))$

Non-capturing group without ORs
 ^(?:(match1)(match2)(match3)(match4)(match5))$
```

I've tried a few other things as well but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: In what flavor of regex are you working?  In C# and PowerShell, the positive lookahead can be used as in this [example](https://regex101.com/r/5P6uXV/1).  In these languages, this can be used to verify that the line is a match, but the match itself returns an empty string.

Comment: This [example](https://regex101.com/r/RoZrVF/1) uses 3 matches, again this works for .NET(C#) which includes PowerShell.

Comment: using A/B/C/D/E instead of match1/match2/etc, is `DE ABCDE ABC` fail/match/fail, or two matches?

Comment: Another .Net [example](https://regex101.com/r/7BS6eJ/1), but this one uses named groups so you can get each individual match, when all matches match.

Comment: In `match1 match4 match2 match5 match4` did you mean for one `match4` to be `match3`? Same with the list below that. Is `match1 != match2` guaranteed? (Same for all 10 pairs.)

Answer (score 0):

If your version of the regular expression supports [back-references](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html), then for your sample data, I would suggest the following variant.

```
\bmatch(1|2|3|4|5)\s+
match(?!\1)(1|2|3|4|5)\s+
match(?!\1)(?!\2)(1|2|3|4|5)\s+
match(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(1|2|3|4|5)\s+
match(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)(1|2|3|4|5)\b
```

Check it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KUhqGd/6).

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\b              # the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
  match         #   'match'
    (1|2|3|4|5) #   group and capture '1', '2', '3', '4', OR '5' to \1
    \s+         #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  match         #   'match'
    (?!\1)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \1
    (1|2|3|4|5) #   group and capture '1', '2', '3', '4', OR '5' to \2
    \s+         #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  match         #   'match'
    (?!\1)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \1
    (?!\2)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \2
    (1|2|3|4|5) #   group and capture '1', '2', '3', '4', OR '5' to \3
    \s+         #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  match         #   'match'
    (?!\1)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \1
    (?!\2)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \2
    (?!\3)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \3
    (1|2|3|4|5) #   group and capture '1', '2', '3', '4', OR '5' to \4
    \s+         #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  match         #   'match'
    (?!\1)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \1
    (?!\2)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \2
    (?!\3)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \3
    (?!\4)      #   look ahead to see if there is not what was matched by capture \4
    (1|2|3|4|5) #   group and capture '1', '2', '3', '4', OR '5' to \5
\b              # the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it your attempt at a positive lookahead is somewhat close to a solution. To be able to have multiple matches we need them to be separated though. In this sample I've added a check to the positive lookaheads not to go passed any empty lines - `(?:(?!\R\R).)*` - a non-capturing group that matches any characters that aren't two consecutive new lines.

After the lookaheads it matches all characters up to an empty line.

Try

```
/(?=(?:(?!\R\R).)*match1)(?=(?:(?!\R\R).)*match2)(?=(?:(?!\R\R).)*match3)(?=(?:(?!\R\R).)*match4)(?=(?:(?!\R\R).)*match5)(?:(?!\R\R).)*/gs
```

(Note Single Line option.)

See it here: https://regex101.com/r/2sU4v1/3. This matches the first and the third group, which meets your requirements. (The second has no `match1`.)

To test just one group, your attempt works fine, which can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/MArppn/2

(Note that your second data sample is wrong though - it has no `match3`.)

And as Darin commented, it may not work in all RE flavors.